# DBMS_JAVA could not be validated or authorized

Tags: database, oracle

I am facing the error while upgrading oracle database 11gR2 to 19c.
Error Code: ORA-04023: Object SYS.DBMS_JAVA could not be validated or authorized.

For example:

```
  SQL> select dbms_java.longname('TEST') from dual;
  select dbms_java.longname('TEST') from dual
  *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-04023: Object SYS.DBMS_JAVA could not be validated or authorized
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dba_registry` should help identify if there is something wrong with your Java version installed in the database.

### Query

```sql
SELECT comp_id, comp_name, version, version_full, status, procedure
  FROM dba_registry
 WHERE comp_id = 'JAVAVM';
```

### Example Result

```
   COMP_ID                       COMP_NAME       VERSION    VERSION_FULL    STATUS                     PROCEDURE
__________ _______________________________ _____________ _______________ _________ _____________________________
JAVAVM     JServer JAVA Virtual Machine    19.0.0.0.0    19.10.0.0.0     VALID     INITJVMAUX.VALIDATE_JAVAVM
```

When looking at `dba_registry`, any components that are not listed as **VALID** can be validated by connecting as **SYS** then running the procedure listed under the `PROCEDURE` column.